# How can I have unit and functional tests for my android independent calsses without needing a device?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-testing

I am developing an android app and I want to be able to test the android independent classes (which basically contain my logic) using junit without needing a device. The question is that is it possible? and if yes, what would be the correct package hierarchy. I've been searching and doing some trial and error (I am using eclipse) but couldn't come to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular unit tests and run them with Eclipse. I used this blog to learn how to write unit tests for android:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

In my apps im using package hierarchy similar to this:

- abc.core - contains all core classes, interfaces and skeleton of infrastructure
- abc.data - contains all data access logic
- abc.logic - contains all business logic and services

and then

- abc.android - contains android project, where your views use mostly abc.logic package

tests:

- abc.core.tests - contains unit tests od core
- abc.data.tests - constains all data tests
- abc.logic.tests - constains all logic tests

I know than the package count is quite high, but I came from .Net world :)